# Use secondary monitor DPI in System DPI aware applications

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, resolution

I run a mixed-DPI multiple monitor setup. The primary monitor is set for use with games, while almost everything else is done on the secondary high-dpi monitor.

Unfortunately this results in a poor experience for applications that are '*System aware*' when it comes to DPI - they are upscaled and therefore pixelated on the secondary monitor. '*Per-monitor aware*' applications work great.

**Is there any way to force a system DPI aware application to run at a particular forced DPI level, rather than inheriting the DPI of the primary monitor?** Windows seems to be designed around preferring the DPI of the primary monitor - I want to prefer a different DPI, without changing the primary monitor.

I imagine it is possible to force with some hooking, but before I go down that route I'm wondering if there is an option or existing solution I'm missing. It is difficult to search for this problem, as the keywords overlap with common DPI problems.

The OS in question is Windows 10.